# How to find matched word only, no substring by using pandas str.extractall?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, text

I am working with a column of string in a dataframe, and trying to extract all words which matched any words in a giving word list. It extracted all matched words and substring, how can I get only words? Many thanks!

My code:

```
import pandas as pd

cl =['dust', 'yes inr', 'inner']
data = [[1, 'dust industr yes inr'], [2, 'state inner'],[3, 'dustry']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Text'])

df['findWord'] = df['Text'].str.extractall(f"({'|'.join(cl)})").groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)

print(df)
```

Current output: how can only extract the word dust, not substring of 'industry'

```
   ID                  Text             findWord
0   1  dust industr yes inr  dust, dust, yes inr
1   2           state inner                inner
2   3                dustry                 dust
```

Expected output:

```
   ID                  Text             findWord
0   1  dust industr yes inr        dust, yes inr
1   2           state inner                inner
2   3                dustry                  Nan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

cl =['dust', 'inner']
data = [[1, 'dust industry inner'], [2, 'state inner'],[3, 'dustry']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Text'])

df['findWord'] = [', '.join(set(d.split(' ')).intersection(set(cl))) for d in df['Text'].to_numpy()]
df = df.replace('', np.NaN)
```

```
   ID                 Text     findWord
0   1  dust industry inner  dust, inner
1   2          state inner        inner
2   3               dustry          NaN
```

**Update 1**:
Try this with a regex pattern:

```
import pandas as pd

cl =['dust', 'yes inr', 'inner']
data = [[1, 'dust industr yes inr'], [2, 'state inner'],[3, 'dustry']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Text'])

regex = '({})'.format('|'.join('\\b{}\\b'.format(c) for c in cl))
df['findWord'] = df['Text'].str.extractall(regex).groupby(level=0).agg(', '.join)
```

```
   ID                  Text       findWord
0   1  dust industr yes inr  dust, yes inr
1   2           state inner          inner
2   3                dustry            NaN
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help! It rise another question, I updated the 'Text' and given words, can you please take a look again? I really appreciate it.

Comment: And in your expected result in the first row: `dust, y inner` <-- why is `inner` not here as a separate result? Since the word `inner` also matches..so what is your logic? @newlearner101

Comment: the given list has single words and phrases, I am trying to extract whenever the words or phrases match the items on the give list. and they can't be substring. I don't know if this makes sense.

Comment: But what if a word matches and also a word in the phrase matches? That is the question I am asking how do you differentiate between words and phrases?

Comment: The given list is a csv file, so one row is an item, I need to find any matched item from the 'Text', sorry about confusion.

Comment: Let me modify the example. does it make a better sense now? Thank you!

Comment: yes, just got it work. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Fix your regex pattern by adding word boundries `\b` so that it only matches full words then use `str.findall` to find all occurrences of this pattern

```
df['findWord'] = df['Text'].str.findall(r'\b(%s)\b' % '|'.join(cl)).str.join(', ')
```

---

```
   ID                  Text       findWord
0   1  dust industr yes inr  dust, yes inr
1   2           state inner          inner
2   3                dustry
```